# How to find ANY records that match a criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a ruby (1.9.3) on rails (3.1) app where:

#### app/models/list.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  #...
end
```

#### app/models/task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  #...
end
```

I am trying to loop through a List's tasks to search if there are ANY tasks that have

```
task.planned_for.blank? or task.mins.blank?
```

Essentially if the loop finds either, I need to conditionally display some view code. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the SQL equivalent of ActiveSupport#blank? is:

```
column_name IS NULL OR column_name = ''
```

so in your controller show method:

```
@list = List.find(params[:id])
@tasks = @list.tasks.where("planned_for IS NULL OR planned_for = '' OR mins IS NULL OR mins = ''")
```

in your view:

```
<% if @tasks.any? %>
  <% #do some stuff %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: SQL string literals use single quotes, `""` may or may not work depending on the database. An alternative is `coalesce(planned_for, '') = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming planned_for and mins are actual Task attributes:

```
List.first.tasks.where('tasks.planned_for IS NULL OR tasks.mins IS NULL')
```

You can also use this condition in a scope on Task:

```
scope :my_scope, -> { where('tasks.planned_for IS NULL OR tasks.mins IS NULL') }
```

So

```
List.first.tasks.my_scope
```

I used the brackets in the scope definition because going without is deprecated on Rails 4 apparently. This is based on NULL rather than #blank because I usually push to not have blank strings in database.